# joomla 3 - jquery-1.10.2.min.js script being removed from <head>

Tags: jquery, joomla3.0, head

I have a problem where the following script is being removed from my 'head':

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Being removed from this page:

http://notjustnappies.medri.co.nz/index.php?option=com_mijoshop&view=category&path=33&Itemid=135

But it shows in the source on the homepage!

Any ideas? just can't figure this out...

Comment: I can clearly see it in `<head></head>` from viewsource! on line no **52**

Comment: Yeah, it is there. Try to clear your browser cache.

Comment: mmm... can you see it on the 'shop' page?

Comment: god dammit ... my bad... i am loading it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I would answer this using a different/better method than you're already doing. Rather than importing jQuery using `<script>` tags, you should import it using Joomla coding standards which will call the jQuery file than comes with the Joomla package like so:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

This will also call it in noConflict mode :)

Hope this helps